# How to enforce long syntax for array declaration in phpstorm?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, phpstorm

I am quite used to using the short array syntax `[]` instead of the longer one `array()`. Now, I am forced by the server environment into using the longer one.

PhpStorm allows to enforce the shorter syntax for arrays in Code Style > Php > Array declaration style > Force short declaration style:

[image: PhpStorm Code Style Array Declartion Style Force Short Style]

Now, I want to achieve the reverse.

Having it automatically replaced would be preferred, but it would already help to mark the short declaration style as an error.

Comment: I have no idea about that IDE, but it probably supports a php version on project level? That should do the trick...

Comment: IDE offers "long/old --> short/new" detection and conversion ONLY (as separate inspection for detection and formatting rule for automatic conversion). Manual conversion can be done in both ways (2 separate intentions exist for this purpose). Your only other choice is to lower language level as already suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Project settings > PHP choose the PHP Language Level to 5.3 and it will mark the short array syntax as error.

Comment: then is there a way to convert all the short syntax back to long?